# Como puede realizar una baja fisica?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy tratando de eliminar registros pero no de la base de datos, sino que no se visualicen en el listado. Para ello utilizo un campo binario llamado estado donde si el valor es  se encuentra activo y si es 1 el registro esta inactivo. Hasta ahora estaba haciendo una baja logica con un metodo delete en mi controlador, pero como quiero tener un registro de todos mis datos en la db ahora necesito que sea solamente fisica. Para ello se me ocurrio en la vista hacer una condicional if donde solo se muestren los registros con estado = 0. Ahora lo que nose como hacer es que cuando toco el boton de eliminar, me modifique el estado de 0 a 1 es decir de activo a inactivo.

Este es mi boton que utilizo para eliminar de la base de datos mi producto:

```
<a title="Delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                        href="{{ route('products.delete', $product->id) }}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Este es mi metodo delete dentro del controlador:

```
public function delete($id){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $product->delete();
    return redirect()->route('products.view');
}
```

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que pase de un estado 1 a un estado 0, entonces no se hace un delete sino un update

Comment: igual.. confundis un delete logico (que es lo que estabas haciendo) con uno fisico (que es borrar el registro)... vos nunca queres borrarlo.. entonces no entiendo bien donde esta tu problema.. si es lo que venias haciendo...

Comment: @gbianchi Esta puesto ahi arriba el metodo delete que pegue en la pregunta es lo que estoy haciendo para hacer el delete logico. Lo que yo quiero hacer es un delete fisico nomas, pero nose como hacer para modificar el valor de un campo de la base de datos desde el controlador.

Comment: un delete fisico borra el registro.. vos queres borrarlo definitivamente?

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres eliminar el registro simplemente realiza un update

```
public function delete($id){
    
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->estado = 1;
        $product->update();
        return redirect()->route('products.view');
}
```

Aunque una mejor solucion seria usar el [softDelete](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Comment: Claro que si se puede usar update() la diferencia con save() es que al usar update si se esta usando timestamp se actualizara la fecha de updated_at y con save() no, pero si se prefiere se puede usar save()